# Curve endged of div tags using Html and css

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to bring curve edges to divs using html and css only...without using images.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127227/css-rounded-corners

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you mean border-radius. Yes, it is possible in proper browsers (not IE) with `border-radius`. As it's a CSS3 property, it's not yet properly implemented and you need to do some trickery to make it work:

```
-moz-border-radius: 10px; /* for firefox */
-webkit-border-radius: 10px; /* for safari & chrome */
border-radius: 10px; /* for others (opera) */
```

Take a look at http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/ for more info.

Answer (score 6):

Not in a way that's compatible cross browser (in particular, IE does not yet support it). In CSS 3, you can use [`border-radius`](http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/), which Safari and Firefox support currently as `-webkit-border-radius` and `-moz-border-radius`. For example

```
<div style="-moz-border-radius: 10px; 
            -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
            border-radius: 10px;
            border: 1px solid #000; 
            padding: 10px;">
  This is a sample div.
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible, but it is a CSS 3 feature that may not work on all browsers (or not the same in all browsers). See [this article](http://www.webcredible.co.uk/user-friendly-resources/css/css-round-corners-boxes.shtml) for an example.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, it, certainly, is technically possible (the best kind of possible, I guess), [here](http://www.spiffycorners.com/) is an example (be sure to check the source, it really is a cool technique).