# What is the css code to make my corners rounded?

Tags: css

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [CSS Rounded corners.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127227/css-rounded-corners)
>   [What is the best way to create rounded corners using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-rounded-corners-using-css)

Can somebody pls give me the css code to make my corners rounded. Pls...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.round {-webkit-border-radius: 8px;
-moz-border-radius: 8px;
border-radius: 8px;
background: #EEFF99;
behavior: url(/PIE.htc);
```

http://css3pie.com/

Answer (score 1):

This will work on most modern browsers

```
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
```

http://border-radius.com/

Answer (score 1):

use images for the rounded corners for backward compatibility, for browsers that dont support highers css